# app.sendFile() is not working and also __dirname is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

i want  to push app on heroku server but __dirname is set as 'app'  which is my app.js file it is not folder and i am working in newapp folder

```
 if(process.env.NODE_ENV==='production'){

app.use(express.static('my-app/build'));

app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
   const index=path.resolve('my-app','build','index.html')
    res.sendfile(index)

})
```

err[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAauc.png)or is:-{"title":"something went wrong","msg":"ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/my-app/build/index.html'"}

please open the above link ,link of photo of my all folder or file name

Comment: "name": "newapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "start-server": "nodemon server.js",
    "start-client": "npm start --prefix my-app",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start-server\" \"npm run start-client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild":"cd my-app && npm install && npm run build"

Comment: FYI, you should be using `path.join()`, not `path.resolve()`.  And, what isn't working about `__dirname`?

Comment: __dirname return app not newapp .please open photo check my folder

Comment: path.resolve() also not working

Comment: i want to deploy mywebsite to heroku  and when i run heroku above error is shown and i check all script compare with other script also but it is not orking